# Cron to run every 15 days regardless of months

Tags: cron

I need a cron expression that runs 15 days every Tuesday regardless if the month is changed.
Example runs:

May 9
May 23
June 6th
June 20th
July 4th

The month does not matter, it must be run every 15 days on Tuesdays

Comment: First run on Tuesday May 2nd, 15 days later is Wednesday 17th...  How can you run every 15th day on a Tuesday?!?

Comment: cron uses the day value as a calendar day, so you cannot do that natively.  What you could do is get cron to start your script every day.  In your script, implement a counter stored in a file.  When the counter is == 15, run the rest of the code and reset it to 0.  Otherwise, just increment the counter value in the file where you store that counter.